# Codemagic with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

i not have an mac for develop with flutter so i use codemagic.
while i build the app i get an error.
I search many time but not find the reason.
I dont know what mean "ARCHIVE FAILED"
Can anyone help me.

```
note: Build preparation complete
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
```

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/builder/programs/flutter_2_2_1/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/Flutter.framework/Flutter' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/builder/programs/flutter_2_2_1/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-armv7_arm64/Flutter.framework/Flutter'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the problem is that there are multiple deployment targets set in your project that contradict. Most likely: your app declares to support iOS 8 and up (I think that's still what ships with the blank/example Flutter apps as well) but some of the plugins that you use only support iOS 9.

Solution:

1. Decide what version you need/want to support.
   At the time of writing this, iOS 14 is out and 15 is announced. Apple officially recommends developers to support the latest two versions. However, in practice what you'll likely need is to support the last 3-4 versions. So iOS 9+ is definitely enough but might even go with 11+.
2. In your `PodFile` (located in your app's `/ios` folder):

Find `platform :ios, '8.0'`
and set the number according to your needs.

3. In your `project.pbxproj` file in the `/ios/Runner.xcodeprojec` folder:

Find all `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0;` lines and set the number here as well.

4. Optionally, if you still have issues, add this to the end of your Podfile:

> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
>     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>           config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
>           config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

This will ensure that all your targets are set properly (instead of step 3). Plus, it will disable bitcode generation which could be an issue with Codemagic as mentioned in this post.